# Running two commands at the same time?

Tags: bash, scripting, parallelism

Here is the nature of my problem:

I'm using my raspberry pi to run a wikipedia server, so I'd like to make a launcher (desktop icon) that starts up the wikipedia server and opens the web browser to localhost:8080. Whenever I'm writing a script to do this it will only do whichever one comes first. For example:

```
./wikipedia_server; ./web_browser
```

When they're separated by a semicolon it waits for the wikipedia server process to finish (which it never does), and then it launches the web browser. If i do

```
./web_browser; ./wikipedia_server
```

then it simply waits until i close the web browser.

Is there any way I could make a small script that would execute both of them at the same time, and if so how would i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could send the wikipedia server to the background, run the web browser, then kill off the server when you're done:

```
./wikipedia_server &
server=$!
# wait for TCP port 8080 to open up
while ! netstat -tln | grep -q :8080; do :; done
./web_browser
kill $server
```

... on the assumption that you don't want the Wikipedia server running unless you are also browsing it.

(updated to add the idea from Ole Tange's comment: to wait for the web server's port to open before continuing)

Comment: This answers the question of running 2 processes at the same time. However whenever I have done this type of thing in the past, the web_browser will be up before the server, and I will get an error. If you can get the server to come up, then fork, then the parent process exit, then you will avoid this race problem.

Comment: A work-around there could be to add a sleep command before starting the browser; experiment with the times to see how long it takes.

Comment: Using sleep can work, but will be slow and/or unreliable.

Comment: Look for a program listening on port 80: netstat -tln4c | perl -ne '/:80 / and exit'

Comment: I updated my answer having now learned about netstat's "listen" and "continuous" flags -- thanks @OleTange!